# Does SQL Server SELECT * INTO temp table preserve exact column data types?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012 - if I do:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp01 
FROM dbo.AnyNormalTable
```

will the columns in the temp table be identical to the standard table?

Comment: Hi fangled, yes they will match the table from which you are selecting.

Comment: This is [explicitly addressed in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql): "Each column in `new_table` has the same name, data type, nullability, and value as the corresponding expression in the select list."

Comment: What is your actual requirement as you can check it also by running the query?

Comment: @fangled unfortunately your google-foo let you down and missed the documentation. But there are actually quite a lot of people around here who really do want to help others. Don't get discouraged by your first post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a table using explicit create table statement versus select into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832181/creating-a-table-using-explicit-create-table-statement-versus-select-into)

Comment: @EricLeFort it doesn't but is a very interesting link nonethless, very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

not necessarily...
If there are user defined types then these might not be created in the temp table - the column will be created as the base type instead. 
An edge case but worth considering ...